# using DO loops to simplify duplicated code

Tags: loops, matrix, fortran

I write out a simple code below without using any DO loops:

```
PROGRAM testrun
INTEGER,PARAMETER :: n=3
INTEGER :: k
REAL :: x(0:n+1),y(0:n+1),h
REAL, PARAMETER :: a = -6, b = 6
DOUBLE PRECISION :: C(n**2,n**2)

h = (b-a)/(n+1)
x = [(a+k*h, k=0, n+1)]
y = [(a+k*h, k=0, n+1)]

C = 0
C(1,1) = x(1)**2 + y(1)**2
C(2,2) = x(2)**2 + y(1)**2
C(3,3) = x(3)**2 + y(1)**2
C(4,4) = x(1)**2 + y(2)**2
C(5,5) = x(2)**2 + y(2)**2
C(6,6) = x(3)**2 + y(2)**2
C(7,7) = x(1)**2 + y(3)**2
C(8,8) = x(2)**2 + y(3)**2
C(9,9) = x(3)**2 + y(3)**2

END PROGRAM
```

How can I fill up the matrix C using DO loops only? I want it to have the exact diagonal form as shown above.  Doing it by hand gets tedious very quickly as my actual problem uses very large values of n, so the n=3 case here is just to show what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work :

```
do j = 1,n
do i = 1,n

    k = (j-1)*(n)+i
    C(k,k) = x(i)**2 + y(j)**2

enddo
enddo
```

Just a check for the case where n = 3 (same as your example) :

```
j = 1, i = 1, k = 1 --> C(1,1) = x(1)**2 + y(1)**2
       i = 2, k = 2 --> C(2,2) = x(2)**2 + y(1)**2
       i = 3, k = 3 --> C(3,3) = x(3)**2 + y(1)**2
j = 2, i = 1, k = 4 --> C(4,4) = x(1)**2 + y(2)**2
       i = 2, k = 5 --> C(5,5) = x(2)**2 + y(2)**2
       i = 3, k = 6 --> C(6,6) = x(3)**2 + y(2)**2  
j = 3, i = 1, k = 7 --> C(7,7) = x(1)**2 + y(3)**2
       i = 2, k = 8 --> C(8,8) = x(2)**2 + y(3)**2
       i = 3, k = 9 --> C(9,9) = x(3)**2 + y(3)**2
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you very much!